# Adding Multiple Linefeed in Confirm dialogue using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

We got an requirement in which we have to add two linefeed after paragraph to make the confirm box look user friendly.

I was able to achieve single line feed on text in confirm dialogue. But when I am adding two line feeds its still taking it as single line feed. Is there any way to add two line feeds to display the text below with some space?

[Confirm Dialogue Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqPdD.png)

Requirement is to display the first line and the second line with having two linefeeds instead of one linefeed. Is it possible to achieve it in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do it using unicode U+2800 Braille Pattern Blank.( \u2800 )

**Example:**

```
Paragraph\n\u2800\nText?
```

**Output in alert/confirm dialogue box:**

Paragraph

Text?